# Server 19.10 on Raspberry Pi 4 defaults to root?

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu, operating-systems, sudo, root

I've successfully installed Server 19.10, then got a desktop (Lubuntu) going on a single Raspberry Pi 4 (4gb). I went with the 32-bit version, having heard the 64-bit is not very stable. (Please contradict me if not so.) Some weirdness came with the desktop (e.g., doesn't show network icon in panel), but basically functional. My problem is the install created a passworded account named `ubuntu`, but this appears to be root. I didn't notice that when doing `sudo apt-get install`, I wasn't being prompted for the password, i.e., this must be root, correct? I blithely installed many packages, moved over files before I noticed this, BTW. So, I assume I really should create a "normal" Ubuntu account with `sudo` privileges? Then I should move everything in this original `/home/ubuntu` user/group-wise over to the normal account? The main reason I'm worried about this is I am a teacher and I want to set up many RPi4's, and they can't all be
 user `ubuntu` with automatic root privileges. What can I do at this point?

**Update**

My `/etc/sudoers` has this

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Inside the `/etc/sudoers.d/` is a file `90-cloud-init-users` which has the line

```
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

which no doubt is why I'm getting no `sudo` prompt. BTW, what is `90-cloud...`?

I guess I need some coaching on how to create a new account user/passwd with good sudo privilege, and then how to move `/home/ubuntu` stuff over to this new account.

Comment: The user ubuntu is not root but the user ubuntu. But it seems that it hast the permission to become root without password. What's he content of `/etc/sudoers` and `/etc/sudoers.d/`?

Comment: *I went with the 32-bit version, having heard the 64-bit is not very stable.* Deal.

Comment: search for *passwordless sudo* - you'll find a lot of information

Comment: @jake See my update.

Comment: So you could just delete that file. How to create new users is also not hard to find on the internet.

Comment: "I am a teacher" - obviously not an English teacher, because your Question is unclear. You appear to be trying to install some version of Ubuntu (as Server and/or Desktop) and are asking basic Linux administration questions (which are off-topic for this site) - get a basic Linux manual or do a Linux admin course.

Comment: Ubuntu (with the possible exception of the Server) is a poor choice for the Pi4 as there is little support, and even expert users have problems. It is doubtful if it offers any advantage over the officially supported OS Raspbian which has extensive support.